# Perform an INSERT in Jena Fuseki with SPARQL gem (Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sparql, apache-jena

So I'm developing an API in Rails and using Jena Fuseki to store triples, and right now I'm trying to perform an INSERT in a named graph. The query is correct, since I ran it on Jena and worked perfectly. However, no matter what I do when using the Rails CLI, I keep getting the same error message:

```
SPARQL::Client::MalformedQuery: Error 400: SPARQL Update: No 'update=' parameter
```

I've created a method that takes the parameters of the object I'm trying to insert, and specified the graph where I want them.

```
def self.insert_taxon(uri, label, comment, subclass_of)
  endpoint = SPARQL::Client.new("http://app.talkiu.com:8030/talkiutest/update")
  query =
     "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
      PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
      PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
      prefix gpc:<http://www.ebusiness-unibw.org/ontologies/pcs2owl/gpc/>
      prefix tk: <www.web-experto.com.ar/ontology#>

      INSERT DATA {
        GRAPH <http://app.talkiu.com:8030/talkiutest/data/talkiu> {
          <#{uri}> a owl:Class.
          <#{uri}> rdfs:label '#{label}'@es .
          <#{uri}> rdfs:comment '#{comment}' .
          <#{uri}> rdfs:subClassOf <#{subclass_of}> .
        }
      }"
  resultset = endpoint.query(query)
end
```

As you can see, I'm using the UPDATE endpoint. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... Instead of endpoint.query, I tried

```
resultset = endpoint.update(query)
```

and worked. Method returned

```
<SPARQL::Client:0x2b0158a050e4(http://app.talkiu.com:8030/talkiutest/update)>
```

and the data is showing up in my database and graph. Hope this helps anyone with the same problem.